# Infinitesimal generator : what is it exactly?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(X_t)$ an diffusion Itô process, i.e. a solution of $$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma (X_t)dB_t.$$ The infinitesimal generator of $(X_t)$ is $$Af(x)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\mathbb E^x[f(X_t)]-f(x)}{t},$$
where $\mathbb E^x$ is the expectation wrt $\mathbb P^x$.

**Q1)** What represent exactly $Af(x)$ for $X_t$ ? For example, for a Brownian motion, if $f$ is $C^2$ then $$A f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\Delta f(x).$$

But I don't really understand which information does $A$ give is. Is it a sort of derivative of $X_t$ ?

**Q2)** What is exactely the measure $\mathbb P^x$ ? I know it is $\mathbb P^x\{X_t\in A\}=\mathbb P(\{X_t\in A\}\mid \{X_0=x\}),$ But does it mean that on $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P^x)$ we have that $\mathbb P\{X_0=x\}=1$ ? (i.e. is deterministic).

Comment: (1) Intuitively, if $X_t$ is a deterministic function of $t$, $Af(x)$ is exactly $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}|_{t=0}f(X_t)$. When $X_t$ is an Ito process, $Af(x)$ measures how "fast" $f(X_t)$ changes with respect to $t$ in the sense of expectation. (2) $\mathbb{P}^x$ is a conditional probability, which conditions on $X_0=x$. That is, $X_t$ has a fixed, deterministic starting point $x$. In this sense, yes, $\mathbb{P}\left\{X_0=x\right\}=1$, which, rigorously, should be $\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_0=x\right\}|\left\{X_0=x\right\}\right)=1$. This is trivially true.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/694227/36150) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2948629/36150)

Comment: @saz : Very nice links. Thank you for this contribution, it's very helpful. I'll probably comment them in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Q1) It seems that [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403083/is-martingale-problem-interesting) could help.

Q2) Also see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496608/formal-definition-of-conditional-probability) for a formal definition of conditional probability. Even, the existence of regular conditional probabilities is a non-trivial fact even for simple cases like $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with Borel sigma algebra.