# Infinitesimal generator - Feller semigroup

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am interested in the infinitesimal generator of the Brownian motion and its relation to the Laplacian. As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694227/what-is-the-importance-of-the-infinitesimal-generator-of-brownian-motion) the infinitesimal generator is defined as

$$
Af(x) := \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x)}{t} = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{P_tf(x)-f(x)}{t}
$$

I would appreciate to answer my questions, by considering the fact that i have not that much knowledge in Stochastic calculus or probability theories.

1) What is $f(x)$?  Can we say that: $Af(x)$  is the generator of the stochastic process $X$? I mean, $Af(x)=AX$?  Also, if X is a function, how can we interpret $f(X)$?

2) Is there any simple way to explain what is $P_tf(x)$, without knowing about feller semigroup? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060561/infinitesimal-generator-what-is-it-exactly) i read that : "$\mathbb{P}^x$ is a conditional probability, which conditions on $X_0=x$". But this is not that much clear for me.

3) As it is written  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694227/what-is-the-importance-of-the-infinitesimal-generator-of-brownian-motion), one can write:

$$
\mathbb{E}^x(f(B_t)) \approx \mathbb{E}^x \left[f(x)+f'(x)(B_t-x)+\frac{1}{2} f''(x)(B_t-x)^2 \right]= f(x)+0+\frac{t}{2} f''(x)
$$

How $\mathbb{E}^xf(x)$ became $f(x)$ in the equality above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The infinitesimal generator is an operator defined on a subspace of the space $C_0$ of continuous functions that vanish at infinity. More precisely, the subspace on which it is defined is
$$D(A) = \left \{f \in C_0: \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}^x(f(X_t))-f(x)}{t} \text{ exists} \right \}$$
and then $A:D(A) \to C_0$. This means that if $f \in D(A)$ then $Af$ is a function that vanishes at infinity. $A$ is the generator of the process $X$ but this does not mean that for $f \in D(A)$, $Af(X) = AX$. Indeed, you have no reason to believe that $X \in D(A)$ in the first place since in many situations $A$ will turn out to be a differential operator and $X$ need not have differentiable paths.

Finally, if $X$ is your process then $f(X)$ is the process that at a given time $t$ and for a given $\omega$ in your probability space is defined by $f(X)_t(\omega) = f(X_t(\omega))$.

(2) $P_t f(x) = \mathbb{E}^x[f(X_t)]$. This is simply the expected value of $f(X_t)$ is your process is started at $x$ at time $0$.

(3) $f(x)$ is deterministic and so $E^x[f(x)] = f(x) E^x[1] = f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About the third point, so why $\mathbb{E}^x(B_t-x)=0$. We know that $\mathbb{E}^x(B_t)=0$. Why $\mathbb{E}^x(x)=0$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}^x$ is the expectation with respect to the law of the Brownian motion started from $x$ and not from $0$. This means that $\mathbb{E}^x[B_t] = x$.

Comment: We shouldn't have $f \in C^2_0$ ?

Comment: At which stage? If you are only interested in the standard Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}$ then $D(A) = C_0^2$. This is a special case of what I wrote in point (1) since $D(A)$ is only a subspace of $C_0$. However $P_t$ is allowed to act on an arbitrary $f \in C_0$ without the assumption that $f \in C^2$.

Comment: @RhysSteele what does it mean that "if $X$ is your process then $f(X)$ is the process given at time t"? E.g. for Brownian motion, $B_t$ is itself the position at time t.

Comment: @Kevin I think you are grouping words in that sentence incorrectly. The wording was unnecessarily confusing so I changed it, hopefully the edited answer is clearer.