# Space of $f$ for infinitesimal generator of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

As written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3653367/767953), we have $f \in C_0$ in general. As discussed in comments, I wonder why/how $f \in C^2_0 $ for Brownian motion? I'd appreciate some explanation for the choice of space in the context of the definition of the infinitesimal generator.

Comment: "Does it mean that the path of the Brownian motion is twice differentiable?" ***Definitely not.*** The generator of a Markov process is a functional analytic object related to its semi group. I'd appreciate some googling before asking for basic explanations.

Comment: Thanks. I edited that. However, the main question is why/how $f\in C^2_0$ was defined.

Comment: The question of yours you linked to is almost four years old and evolved around the same topic. Why/how $C^2_0$ is defined becomes pretty obvious by looking at the [usual suspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis): it is the space of twice continuously partial differentiable functions vanishing at infinity.

Comment: the infinitesimal generator of Brownian Motion is the Laplacian, which is only defined for twice differentiable functions.

Comment: Thank you. Why it must vanish at infinity?

Comment: It simply depends on what you are interested. For general Markov theory, there is no need to look at functions that vanish at infinity. However, if you want to use stronger properties of Feller processes, you want to look at continuous functions that vanish at infinity.